# How to modify the size of the grid.extra output using knitr?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, grid-layout, gridextra

I'm having some confusion with the size(s) of the grid.extra output.

I have the following ggplots:

```
k_uniforme <- covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "rectangular",  bw = hsilv, fill="#440154ff") +
  labs(title="Uniform") +
  theme_classic()

k_triangular <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "triangular",  bw = hsilv, fill="#7ad151ff") +
  labs(title="Triangular") +
  theme_classic()

k_gaussian <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "gaussian",  bw = hsilv, fill="#414487ff") +
  labs(title="Gausiana") +
  theme_classic()

k_epanechnikov <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "epanechnikov",  bw = hsilv, fill="#fde725ff") +
  labs(title="Epanechnikov") +
  theme_classic()

k_biweight <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "biweight",  bw = hsilv, fill="#fde725ff") +
  labs(title="Epanechnikov") +
  theme_classic()
```

And I want to print all of them in only one figure, preferably in the size of one entire page.

When I use the grid.arrange function for **four of my plots** I get the following output after kniting for pdf, which is very acceptable in terms of the size of the plots.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(k_uniforme, k_triangular, k_gaussian, k_epanechnikov, ncol=2, nrow=2)
```

[image: Screenshot of the PDF output]

However, when I want to arrange all of them (**5 plots**) the size of each plot is completely different and looks bad.

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(k_uniforme, k_triangular, k_gaussian, k_epanechnikov, k_biweight, ncol=2, nrow=3)
```

[image: Screenshot of the PDF output]

My questions are the following:
What is the default size of each plot in the 4plot-arrange?
Is there any way to make the size of each plot in the 5plot-arrange similar to the one of the 4-plot arrange?
And, How to center the 5th plot (i.e. the one in the third row) of the 5plot-arrange?

I've been searching for any help of grid.extra but the helps, blogs, etc. are really confusing.
The document I'm trying to generate is a pdf using rmarkdown.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution to my problems.

I just realized that I was mixing some things.

First, the size of the grid.arrange figure is adjusted by the definition of the height and width options defined in my chunk. Therefore I adjusted it properly using fig.width and fig.height as already explained in the RMarkdown Cookbook by Yuhui (see [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html) and [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#plots) for additional info).

For my last question about how to center the last plot in the 5-plot arrange I was missing the layout_matrix option of the grid.arrange function. It is partially responded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495107/arrange-three-plots-of-the-same-size-on-two-rows-in-ggplot2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685485/how-do-i-leave-the-graph-centralized-by-ggplot2).

In the layout matrix I defined the positions of the plots I wanted to include. Consider the following:

```
layout_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, NA), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)
```

Which returns a matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    2
[2,]    3    3    4    4
[3,]   NA    5    5   NA
```

The numbers define the plots supplied into the function (i.e. 1 to 5) and their position. The NA can also be substituted for a 6 because I do not have a sixth plot (I prefer NA because is more intuitive).

In the grid.arrange I just defined the matrix as:

```
grid.arrange(k_uniforme, k_triangular, k_gaussian, k_epanechnikov, k_biweight, layout_matrix = layout_matrix)
```

My final code looks like this:

```
{r kernel, fig.cap="Graficas con diferentes densidad Kernel", fig.width=7, fig.height=10}

k_uniforme <- covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "rectangular",  bw = hsilv, fill="#440154ff") +
  labs(title="Uniform") +
  theme_classic()

k_triangular <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "triangular",  bw = hsilv, fill="#7ad151ff") +
  labs(title="Triangular") +
  theme_classic()

k_gaussian <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "gaussian",  bw = hsilv, fill="#414487ff") +
  labs(title="Gausiana") +
  theme_classic()

k_epanechnikov <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "epanechnikov",  bw = hsilv, fill="#fde725ff") +
  labs(title="Epanechnikov") +
  theme_classic()

k_biweight <-  covid %>%
  drop_na(PC) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=PC)) + 
  stat_density(kernel = "biweight",  bw = hsilv, fill="#F24D29") +
  labs(title="biweight") +
  theme_classic()

layout_matrix <- matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, NA, 5, 5, NA), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)

grid.arrange(k_uniforme, k_triangular, k_gaussian, k_epanechnikov, k_biweight, layout_matrix = layout_matrix)
```

And my pdf document looks perfect:

[Screenshot of pdf output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWnk2.png)